# Как сделать выезжающее меню сбоку на Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Собственно есть меню бутстрапа, навбар, нужно реализовать моб версию, чтобы при клике на кнопку меню выезжало с правой стороны. Скажите пожалуйста, как реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте данное расширение для bootstrap - [jasny](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/)